# Deploy gitlab pages using downstream stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

This is my folder tree:

```
proj/
 ├─ src/
 ├─ docs/
 │  ├─ public/
 │  │  ├─ assets/
 │  │  ├─ index.html
 │  ├─ .gitlab-ci.yml
 ├─ config/
 ├─ .gitlab-ci.yml
```

As you can see there are two `.gitlab-ci.yml` files. The first, in the root of the project is the `master` pipeline that trigger the second one into the `docs` folder. I would like that the first pipeline in addition to deploy the application (only on a specific branch) trigger the second pipeline and deploy the documentation on `giltab pages`.

This is the code of the `docs/.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: alpine:latest

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo 'Nothing to do...'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public/
    expire_in: 1 day
```

And this is is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the project's root:

```
stages:
  - deploy-docs
  - gen-text
  - deploy-in-dev

gen-text:
  stage: gen-text
  image: python:3.10.0
  before_script:
    - pip3 install -r ./command/requirements.txt
  script:
    - python3 ./command/main.py
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - src/languages
    expire_in: 1 day
  only: ['stg']

deploy-in-dev:
  stage: deploy-in-dev
  image: node:latest
  dependencies:
    - gen-text
  script:
    - echo 'Only stg with artifacts'
  only: ['stg']

docs:
  stage: deploy-docs
  trigger:
    include: docs/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

The pipeline trigger correctly the downstream but it's fail: `missing pages artifacts`.
So, how can I pass the public folder to the downstream and why the secondary `.gitlab-ci.yml` doesn't see the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the path that you provided for the artifacts in downstream

```
paths:
- public/
```

You should change it to

```
paths:
- docs/public/
```

When you include the child pipeline the current working directory doesn't change, it still is in `proj/` and not in  `docs/`

Comment: Thank you so much! I suppose that the working directory swith to the sub-pipeline. Now, the deploy end correctly but when I open the page it's not found. From what it can be due?